# SharePoint 2013 Project - Adding New Project Site errors

Tags: sharepoint-server, project-server

I am trying to create a new Project Site.
I have followed below steps:

**Step 1: Create a Host Site Named Collection on url**

```
New-SPSite "<Site collection url>" -HostHeaderWebApplication "<Web Application Name>" -Name "<Enter Name>" -Description "<Enter Description>" -OwnerAlias "domain\username" -language 1033 -Template "PWA#0"
```

**Step 2: Create a Project Web App database**

```
New-SPProjectDatabase –Name ProjectServer -ServiceApplication "Project Server Service" -DatabaseServer ServerName -Tag "PS2013"
```

**Step 3: Enable the Project Web App site collection features**

```
$web=Get-SPWeb siteurl
$web.Properties[“PWA_TAG”]=”PS2013″
$web.Properties.Update()
Enable-SPFeature pwasite -URL siteurl
```

Now everything worked fine in our Test environment, which is a complete replica of our Production environment.
BUT when I try this in our Production environment I get an error in Step 3 line 2. Error is:

[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having same or similar issue: I fixed it as noticed that I set the OwnerAlias to one value but was executing the Powershell script with another user (which did not have access to the newly created site collection). Once I executed Powershell with the user I set as the Site Owner, everything worked fine.